# using user input such as YES and NO to control program flow in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm making a small program that uses a if else statement, but instead of using numbers to control the flow i want to be able to make the control work with with yes and no;

for example:

```
cout << "would you like to continue?" << endl;
cout << "\nYES or NO" << endl;
int input =0;
cin >> input;
string Yes = "YES";
string No = "NO";

if (input == no)
{
    cout << "testone" << endl;
}
if (input == yes)
{
    cout << "test two" << endl;
         //the rest of the program goes here i guess?
}
else
{
    cout <<  "you entered the wrong thing, start again" << endl;
              //maybe some type of loop structure to go back
}
```

but I can't seem to get any variations of this to work, i could make the user type a 0 or 1 instead but that seems really stupid, i'd rather it be as natural as possible, users don't speak numbers do they?

also i need to be able to simply add more words, for example "no NO No noo no n" all would have to mean no

hopefully that makes some sense

also i would love to make this using a window but i've only learned basic c++ so far not even that and i cant find any good resources online about basic windows programming.

Comment: This is not Windows programming. This is just standard, platform-independent C++. I suggest you read any beginners C++ book, and not look for Windows programming tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not reading in a `string`, you're reading in an `int`.

Try this:

```
string input;
```

instead of

```
int input = 0;
```

Also, C++ is case-sensitive, so you can't define a variable called `Yes` and then try to use it as `yes`. They need to be in the same case.

btw, your second `if` statement should be an `else if`, otherwise if you type in "NO" then it will still go into that last `else` block.

Comment: string input; is enough, no need to initialize it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `input` must be `std::string`, not `int`.

Also, you've written `yes` and `no` wrong:

```
             v
if (input == No)
// ..
//                v
else if (input == Yes)
^^^^
```

If you want your program to work with "no no no ..", you could use `std::string::find`:

```
if( std::string::npos != input.find( "no" ) )
// ..
```

The same with "Yes".

Also, you could do this to be almost case-insensitive - transform the input to upper-case letters (or lower, whatever ), and then use `find`.This way, `yEs` will be still a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
string input;
cin >> input;
if (input == "yes"){

}
else if (input == "no"{

}

else {
    //blah
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool yesno(char const* prompt, bool default_yes=true) {
  using namespace std;
  if (prompt && cin.tie()) {
    *cin.tie() << prompt << (default_yes ? " [Yn] " : " [yN] ");
  }
  string line;
  if (!getline(cin, line)) {
    throw std::runtime_error("yesno: unexpected input error");
  }
  else if (line.size() == 0) {
    return default_yes;
  }
  else {
    return line[0] == 'Y' || line[0] == 'y';
  }
}
```